# How can I use a transform on images in a body field that have been imported?

Tags: assets, image-transforms, responsive-images

I have imported content into an old news entrytype for a news channel.
The odd image in the body field is 4000px wide.

Is there a way of automatically transforming these in a template or from the CLI?

Im looking at batch processing with Imagemagick but i dont really want to destroy the high res versions by doing this.

Comment: Approx. how many entries/images are we talking about here?

Comment: I ended up using imagick cli as it was just a few volumes and only a few hundred entries.....curious if it's possible though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be done using [Retcon](https://github.com/mmikkel/Retcon-Craft) - more specifically:

https://github.com/mmikkel/Retcon-Craft/wiki/Transform